# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum with malloc_error

Tags: iphone, malloc, wallpaper

I have an NIB file with a button. When I click this button, the setWallpaper: selector is called. Everything works as expected (the image is saved), excepte by the error thrown by malloc.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x184d000: pointer being freed was not allocated ***
set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I've set a breakpoint at malloc_error_break, but I don't understand anything from the debugger. I couldn't even find the object 0x184d000. Does anyone know why is this happening? I had also tried to retain the UIImage before sending it to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, but without success.

My code is below:

```
- (IBAction)setWallpaper:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpaper_01.png"];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
          initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Galo!!!",@"Saved image message: title")
                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Now, check your \"saved photos\" group at \"photos\" app in your iPhone and select the actions menu > set as wallpaper.",@"Saved image message")
               delegate:nil
      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"OK Button")
      otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alertView show];
   [alertView release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after cloning almost my entire project, I realized that the problem comes from OS3.0. Changed to OS3.1 and everything works just fine. Thanks for the help, Carl!

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` does the saving asynchronously, which means you have to make sure your `UIImage` stays around for that whole time.  You're passing it an autoreleased object, so it's crashing sometime out there trying to do the save.  Change `setWallpaper:` to send `retain` to the `UIImage`.  Then you can `release` or `autorelease` it in your callback to avoid leaking.  An example:

Change the line that gets the image:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpaper_01.png"] retain];
```

Then add

```
[image release];
```

in the callback.

Comment: I did that... and still getting the same error... By the way, I get two error messages from the malloc. Both exactly the same. Now I created an empty project, and copied my ViewController + NIB and it worked fine there... I'll check it any framework or lib added to the project is causing a bug...